# Button changing position after setScale android studio

Tags: android, button, position, scale

After changing scale of a button it changes position. But its coordinates don't change. What can I do to keep top-left corner of the control in place?

Comment: Which animation do you use? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have posted zero code. Usually when asking questions, you should provide code for us to evaluate.

Use a relative layout, and use these attributes on your button

```
<Button
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Comment: Good answer, but it probably should have been posted in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm new to answering questions on SO. What is the criteria for posting as an answer rather than a comment? Thanks.

Comment: You have edited your answer since I posted that.  An answer should answer the question.  I'm not saying you were wrong (you were completely right), but it would be best to save the answer space for an answer to the question, in case the question is edited.  I'm not trying to be mean, hopefully you understand.